# Oracle 11g - why is SELECT COUNT(*) infinitely slower than SELECT *?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query in Oracle 11g like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM CATAT, CG, CCSD
WHERE CATAT.ID = 1007642
AND CG.C_ID = CATAT.ID
AND CATAT.IS_PARENT = 1
AND CCSD.G_ID = CG.ID
```

The query, in this instance, comes back with zero rows, and does so pretty much instantly. However, if I change it to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT
FROM CATAT, CG, CCSD
WHERE CATAT.ID = 1007642
AND CG.C_ID = CATAT.ID
AND CATAT.IS_PARENT = 1
AND CCSD.G_ID = CG.ID
```

It NEVER comes back - I have left the query running for over 5 minutes and it still hasn't finished. In fact, anything except SELECT * takes an extremely long time to run. E.g. `SELECT CG.ID FROM...`, or `SELECT CATAT.* FROM...`

The only thing unusual about this query is that the CCSD table has millions of rows of data in it. There is an index on `CCSD.G_ID`, so it can't be a lack of indexes.

I just don't understand why a query that returns zero rows instantly with a `SELECT *` should take so long if you do anything other than that? Can anyone shed some light on this?

### UPDATE

Here is the explain plan for the `SELECT * FROM...` query:
[image: explain plan 1]

Here is the explain plan for the `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM...` query:
[image]

Comment: Can you put in the explain plan for both the queries?

Comment: As requested, I have posted the explain plans!

Comment: What happens if you try `select count(*) from (<your root select * query>)`?

Comment: Try COUNT(1) instead of COUNT(*).

Comment: Russel.. count(*) and count(1) are same. Refer this below post from Tom Kyte
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245

Comment: Are you using any IDE? Did you try executing both the queries in SQL*Plus?

Comment: perhaps your first query is simply pulled from cache.  meaning you (or someone else) ran that exact query already and the results are ready instantly (you say it comes back instantly, which makes me think this is the case).

Comment: @willOEM I tried this, and thought it might work, but it makes no difference!

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan I am using SQL Developer, but exactly the same problem is reproduced in my PHP application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What happens if you run this query instead?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT
FROM CATAT
WHERE CATAT.ID = 1007642
AND CATAT.IS_PARENT = 1
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CG WHERE CG.C_ID = CATAT.ID AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CCSD WHERE CCSD.G_ID = CG.ID))
```

I believe the problem is in the double join you have in the query,

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

To elaborate a little bit more, in your original query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT
**FROM CATAT, CG, CCSD**
WHERE CATAT.ID = 1007642
AND CG.C_ID = CATAT.ID
AND CATAT.IS_PARENT = 1
AND CCSD.G_ID = CG.ID
```

The second line is the problem, when you list additional tables in a from clause in Oracle it means you are writing an implicit join IF and only if you list and match all the primary keys on each table with another column on a different table. Depending on the primary key components you add on the where clause it will result on a regular inner join (if you match all the primary key columns) or it can result on something similar to a cartesian product which I believe is the case by the plans you posted in the images, I can see a merge join with option cartesian in the query plan.

All this means that the database is generating a really big table, and the number of rows in that table is all the rows in CCSD * all the rows in CG * all the rows in CATAT (CCSD has a few millions as you stated so this results in the slowness you perceive) and after that is trying to traverse this temporary table checking the filters you have in place.

This problem is happening because the original query is not optimized for the task, and the one I posted is.

What I did was read you query to have an idea of what are you trying to do, you are trying to list a subset of the table CATAT with a specific ID and with IS_PARENT = 1, but you only want to list those ones whose ID (CATAT.ID) is on (or exists on) the table CG AND in the table CCSD. When writing the query I tried to use the same cascading you have in the conditionals, but the query I posted originally can be written like this also:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS ROW_COUNT
FROM CATAT
WHERE CATAT.ID = 1007642
AND CATAT.IS_PARENT = 1
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CG WHERE CG.C_ID = CATAT.ID )
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CCSD WHERE CCSD.G_ID = CATAT.ID)
```

Now this query does exactly the same as the original one you wrote, but without a join. To solve this query the database traverses the table CATAT matching by ID and IS_PARENT(having an index makes this really fast), once a row matches the first two conditions the databse tries to find an existing record by C_ID on the table CG (again really fast if you have an index) and after that it tries to do the same with the table CCSD by ID. This last 2 searches are in cascade in the first query I posted, but the idea is the same: your query is running slow because is creating a cartesian product (maybe optimized, but still resulting in a large number of rows) while the one I wrote is just traversing tables by ID (no merges), which probably already have indexes in those columns and that's why it is running fast.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Somehow this works - could you explain why?

Comment: I edited the answer to explain a little bit more why it works faster, hope it helps

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation - I think there are probably many other places in my program which could benefit from this type of optimisation!

Comment: How is this the answer? You didn't explain why Oracle execute SELECT differently from COUNT(*).  You posted original query and said that it has the problem but that query does not have the problem and explain plan is different than COUNT

Comment: The question wasn't why Oracle executes both queries differently, it was about the time it takes to execute and it is explained adobe.

Answer (score 3):

If you are evaluating the performance of your query in some SQL development environment like Toad or SQL Developer it's not a true comparison. Most IDE's fetch the first *n* rows (usually 50 rows). <s>by wrapping your query with a</s>

```
SELECT * FROM (your query) WHERE ROWNUM <= 50
```

Often with a stopkey hint. This means the DB only fetches the first 50 rows and stops. However, your `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` is forcing the DB to actually count each and every row the query returns and that takes as long as it takes.

**Edit:** I was thinking of another Oracle product (Apex) when I stated your SQL Developer query is wrapped in a rownum query. That is incorrect. Apparently SQL Developer sets an arraysize for your session per your preference. Nevertheless, fetching 50 rows and stopping will always be faster than forcing a count of all rows.

**Edit 2:** Fair enough, I had thought I understood this question and the SQL Developer fetch size, but nope. I'll leave my answer here as a cautionary example of assumptions.

Comment: It's often true, however queries in the question return **no rows** (count(*) gives 0) - in this case Oracle must read all data from tables to find at the end that the result is empty.

Comment: You're on the right track, but tools like SQL Developer etc. don't wrap queries with a ROWNUM condition, they just don't fetch all the rows until needed.

Comment: Hi, I am using SQL Developer, but this situation also occurs in my program which is written in PHP, using the oci library.

Comment: The arraysize has nothing to do with how many rows are actually displayed in the client. It's only a configuration option to minimize network roundtrips in case rows *are* retrieved.